# Why do you have to explicitly join threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So this seems pretty straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void second() {
    cout << "Don't thread on me!" << endl;
}

int main() {
    thread t { second };
    t.join();

    return 0;
    cin.get();
}
```

If I don't include `join()` then the system calls `abort()`. I don't understand this, shouldn't the thread exit on its own? Having to join threads seems like it will make the code harder to encapsulate properly. What's the deal with this?

Comment: Here is a good reading about this : http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/joinable-and-detached-threads/

Comment: `main` must return `int`.

Comment: That won't compile because it's missing a couple of `#include` directives. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @chris: main does that implicitly if omitted…

Comment: @MFH, I was talking about the return type. Only a return type of `int` is permitted by the standard.

Comment: @chris: I know, the code must have been edited, because it was already `int main()` when I made that comment.

Comment: @MFH, Oh, I see. I didn't notice it changed.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it. Although, for the record Visual Studio (albeit non-standard) does accept `void` as a valid return type for `main()`. Until Jetbrains releases a c++ editor I'm afraid I'll be sticking with it, despite its many compliancy issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is part of the design of the C++ threading library. You don't *need* to `join` the thread, you can also `detach` it. But I would not recommend that you default to `detach`-ing threads, as that brings it's own set of complications.

Contrary to what you are saying, I don't think this makes the code harder to encapsulate at all. There are different levels of abstraction, and choosing the thread level means that you need to be aware that there are threads and you need to handle them.

For different things you may choose different levels of abstractions, for example:

```
int main() {
   auto f = std::async([](){ std::cout << "Don't tread on me\n" << std::flush; });
   f.get();      // Wait for the task to complete
}
```

Comment: Ah, I haven't touched `async` yet.

Comment: @sircodesalot: `thread`s are low level primitives. Even the `std::future<>`/`std::promise<>`/`std::async` are not that high level, but the standard needed to start with something that could be agreed on. I imagine more and more high level contructs will be proposed for standarization in the near future. And there are already libraries for concurrency that offer higher level tools.

Comment: **30.3.1.3** [ Note: Either implicitly detaching or joining
a joinable() thread in its destructor could result in difficult to debug correctness (for detach) or
performance (for join) bugs encountered only when an exception is raised. Thus the programmer must
ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable. —end note ]

Comment: (Just wanted to add a comment on the reasons the standard gives for not joining a thread directly)

Comment: @Juan Note that Herb recently proposed in [N3636](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3636.pdf) that the destructor be changed to call `join()` but the proposal was voted down (for reasons I haven't been able to uncover).

Answer (score 4):

By default threads have to join so that the spawning thread can keep track of and wait for its children to complete (for example you delegate a bunch of work to 2+ threads and then join them all to signal when the work is done).

You can use `detach` to cause the thread to detach from its spawning thread and that will cause the threads to run independently.

Comment: Aha! That's interesting.